# Aws::S3::Client.upload_part_copy ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, multipart

I am attempting to use Aws::S3::Client.upload_part_copy (Ruby SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#upload_part_copy-instance_method ) and am having some difficulties.  I have to use this due to the file I am copying being over 5GB in size.  I have written some code but am getting a Access Denied (Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied) error when running though the multipart upload.  I know that the credentials are correct and I am able to use the Aws::S3::Client otherwise.  Below is a test to copy the file using multipart.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there some other authentication that is required?  Are there some special perms needed on my s3 bucket?  I know that I need to assemble a hash of the parts and call complete_multipart_upload but cannot even get that far.

TIA

```
t = $LargeFileKeyExisting
to = $NewLargeFileKey

size = 5880862890 # hardcoded for now size of large file in bytes
chunk = 104857600 # I Want to use 100 MB chunks
beg_byte = 1
part = 0

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    access_key_id: $myKey,
    secret_access_key: $mySecretKey,
    region: $MyRegion
)
tt = s3.create_multipart_upload({bucket: $MyBucket, key: to})

loop do

 part += 1
 beg_byte = beg_byte
 end_byte = beg_byte + chunk
 end_byte = (end_byte > 5880862890) ? size : end_byte
 puts "part beg: #{beg_byte} - end: #{end_byte} part#{part}"

  resp = s3.upload_part_copy({
   bucket: $MyBucket,
   copy_source: t,
   copy_source_range: "bytes=#{beg_byte}-#{end_byte}",
   key: to,
   part_number: part,
   upload_id: tt[:upload_id],
   })
 break if end_byte == size
 beg_byte = end_byte + 1
end
```

Comment: Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu-ruby-sdk.html you should use [`create_multipart_upload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#create_multipart_upload-instance_method), [`upload_part`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#upload_part-instance_method) and [`complete_multipart_upload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#complete_multipart_upload-instance_method) methods

Comment: Thanks Martin I had an error in my upload key structure thanks for replying causing the error ( it just wasn't a very clear error).